# Why change to same variable in one anonymous class is not visible in another anonym class in java?

Tags: java, variables

I have interesting issue which somebody should explain.

My code is simple:

```
public class SaveFileChooser extends BaseFileChooser {

    private String selectedFilePath = null;

    public SaveFileChooser(String title) {
        super(title);

        super.addPropertyChangeListener(FILE_FILTER_CHANGED_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

                System.out.println(" selectedFilePath=" + selectedFilePath);

            }
        });

        super.addPropertyChangeListener(SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                selectedFilePath = String.valueOf(evt.getNewValue());
                System.out.println("selectedFilePath=" + selectedFilePath);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you see `selectedFIlePath` variable is assigned to value in below listener for `SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY` property.

And in above listener the value of this var is read. I clearly see on console that at first
I assign new non-null value in bottom listener and then read it in above listener.

Unfortunately `selectedFilePath` in above listener is always null. Why is that?

Comment: You didn't changed the value of `selectedFIlePath` in the first listener, so if the first listener invoked first the `selectedFIlePath` will be null

Comment: He mentioned that he can see the output where the file path is assigned.

Comment: Could the writing and the reading occur in different threads? If yes, you should add the `volatile` keyword to your field declaration (selectedFilePath).

Comment: The problem was that below listener assigned null after needed value. I didn't notice this.